# Why it is not possible to whitelist IPv6 networks on Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Only networks with IPv4 can be whitelisted to access Google Cloud SQL databases.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud SQL Second Generation instances architecture is tightly coupled with Google Compute Engine infrastructure. IPv6 is supported on GCE only partially, so as soon GCE fully supports it, you can expect IPv6 support for Cloud SQL to follow suit shortly after.

Relevant: https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/302595-compute-engine/suggestions/8518246-support-ipv6